# javascript: Making a async loop synchronous

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

My nodejs code has a loop that calls a Promise-returning function:

```
collection.forEach((item) => {
    promiseReturningFunction(item);
});
```

The problem is, the backend that is receiving these calls is not that great at handling concurrent requests.

So I want to slow down this loop, each turn waiting for the previous promise to finish. Effectively making it synchronous.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have access to `async` + `await`?

Comment: Check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45349880/5452965) as a possible idea, you can take the code and modify it to fit your needs

Comment: You have several options: combine array functions with the Promise API (still smells like async), use some vendor Promise API (i.e. [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html) - still smells a bit async), use [`coroutines`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html) with Generators (Node > 4), use `async/await` (Node > 7.5). In my experience the `coroutines` + Generator worked pretty well with dev coming from Python.